# Unresolved reference to view model

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build

I am having some problems with my import statements of my view model class. If I clean or add a single line in the two ViewModels that causes the errors, and their dependencies, I can build one more time successfully. But gives me ‘Unresolved reference’ on a bunch of my injected view models if I change anything in my activities/fragments and try and build again without cleaning.

I have tried all different kinds of configurations in my gradle files, to no avail.
I tried different android studio versions, different Hilt versions, Kotlin versions. Invalidating cache, restarting and everything else. Please someone help me!

I have tried to paste my configuration below, together with my MainActivity import statements and one of the viewmodels the Unresolved Reference is referring to.

Main Activity

```
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.fauna.fauna.appointments.AppointmentsViewModel
import com.fauna.fauna.clinic.ClinicViewModel
import com.fauna.fauna.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.fauna.fauna.dischargeNotes.DischargeNotesViewModel
import com.fauna.fauna.vaccinationCards.VaccinationCardsViewModel
import com.fauna.fauna.updateApp.UpdateAppDialogFragment
import com.fauna.fauna.user.UserViewModel
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope { 

    private val vaccinationCardsViewModel: VaccinationCardsViewModel by viewModels()

    //Some functionality 
}
```

VaccinationCardsViewModel

```
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.fauna.fauna.fragment.VaccinationCardDetail
import com.fauna.fauna.util.NotificationService
import com.fauna.fauna.util.Result
import com.fauna.fauna.util.SnackBarViewModel
import com.fauna.fauna.util.getSeconds
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ConflatedBroadcastChannel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.catch
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class VaccinationCardsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val vaccinationCardsRepository: VaccinationCardsRepository,
    private val notificationService: NotificationService
) : SnackBarViewModel() { //Some functionality}
```

build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
    ext.apollo_version = '2.5.5'
    ext.hilt_version = '2.37'
    def nav_version = '2.3.2'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle app file

```
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("com.apollographql.apollo").version("$apollo_version")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id('com.google.gms.google-services')
    id('com.google.firebase.crashlytics')
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debugConfig {
            //..omittet..
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fauna.fauna"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 15
        versionName "0.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    buildTypes {
        //..Omittet..

    }
    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'

    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'

    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // Feature module Support
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"

    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha06"
    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha03"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //View model
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6"

    // Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

hilt {
    enableExperimentalClasspathAggregation = true
}

apollo {
    generateKotlinModels.set(true)
}

beforeEvaluate {
    getApiKey()
}

def getSecretKey(string) {
    def keysFile = file("secret.properties")
    def keysProperties = new Properties()
    keysProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keysFile))
    def key = keysProperties[string]
    println "key: " + key
    return key
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Error upon building the project without cleaning:

```
Task :app:compileDevKotlin

e: /main/java/com/fauna/fauna/MainActivity.kt: (19, 41): Unresolved reference: VaccinationCardsViewModel

e: /main/java/com/fauna/fauna/MainActivity.kt: (21, 29): Unresolved reference: UserViewModel

e: /main/java/com/fauna/fauna/MainActivity.kt: (47, 44): Unresolved reference: VaccinationCardsViewModel

e: /main/java/com/fauna/fauna/MainActivity.kt: (47, 73): Not enough information to infer type variable VM

e: /main/java/com/fauna/fauna/MainActivity.kt: (47, 73): Property delegate must have a 'getValue(MainActivity, KProperty<*>)' method. None of the following functions is suitable: 
public inline operator fun <T> Lazy<???>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): ??? defined in kotlin

e: /main/java/com/fauna/fauna/MainActivity.kt: (49, 32): Unresolved reference: UserViewModel

e: /main/java/com/fauna/fauna/MainActivity.kt: (49, 49): Not enough information to infer type variable VM

e: /main/java/com/fauna/fauna/MainActivity.kt: (49, 49): Property delegate must have a 'getValue(MainActivity, KProperty<*>)' method. None of the following functions is suitable: 
public inline operator fun <T> Lazy<???>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): ??? defined in kotlin

e: /main/java/com/fauna/fauna/MainActivity.kt: (175, 93): Unresolved reference: it
```

Comment: For some more explanation of how to resolve the issue. I asked a question on apollo-android project page, with steps to reproduce
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/3306

Before resolving the issue i created a dagger issue
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the generated files from both Hilt and my Apollo schema files. I had a package within my android project called `user` and a subfolder in my Apollo schema directory called `User` which apparently confuses android studio on subsequent builds. The solution is to either delete the subfolders in the Apollo schema directory or name the packages in the project differently from subfolders in the schema directory.

Answer (score 1):

Hi your hilt versions might be wrong i had similar issues and this follwoing setup worked for me changing it to 2.34-beta, can you please try the following in build gradle app

```
//Dagger - Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.34-beta"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.34-beta"

//extra dagger hilt dependecies for view model lifecycle attaching for your reference
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03'
```

and also change min sdk version to

```
  minSdk 24
```

my kotlin gradle plugin is 1.5.10 in project level (if it helps)

Comment: I tried, I still get Unresolved Reference. Those dependencies are quite old versions, why do you use so old versions?

Comment: well because i was trying to do an app with jetpack compose and all the latest dependencies on hilt were giving issues since JPC was in beta as well, my goal was to learn JPC not to make sure the all my dependencies are up2date. I had all the issues you are facing as well. So after reading countless forums in which many had commented 2.34-beta to be the best i decided to go with it.

Comment: Alright, cheers. They really outdid themselves with the versioning of gradle and hilt. It is so hard to figure out which versions work together across gradle, hilt, viewmodel and android studio. Thanks for the answer, I managed to figure it out in the end and have added a answer with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me I have just added the view model life cycle dependency as follow:

```
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
```